# how the below cases execute and how can i do it more efficient into the memory and performance related?

Tags: c#, linq

Case 1:

```
var lstUsers = MyProgram.GetUsres();

if(lstUsers.Any()){
    string ExistingUser = lstUser.First().UserName;
}
```

CASE 2:

```
if(MyProgram.GetUsres().Where(qry => qry.UserName.Lower("xyz").Any()){
    string ExistingUser = MyProgram.GetUsres().Where(qry => qry.UserName.Lower("xyz")).First().UserName;
}
```

please help me to understand which case can take more time and memory to run this above code?

why?

Comment: Logically they are completely different for starters...

Comment: I'd say the second one will take more time and resources, because you're doing the query twice. Of course this is assuming `GetUsers()` in Case 1 will return an `IQueriable` which doesn't return all the data at once.

Comment: I doubt this would even compile: ..`.Where(qry => qry.UserName.Lower("xyz").Any().First().UserName;`... as `.Any()` returns a `bool`. Could you please double-check your code?

Comment: @Madushan LINQ queries are cached for you as at .NET 4.5. Assuming that's the case here.. there wouldn't be that much of a difference. Although, a compiled one would be better.

Comment: Oops.. My bad.. sorry, I forgot that.

Comment: I got your point madhushan. But i heard that LINQ queries are only executed or fetching the results when it is really executed but not at a point where it is defined. So thats why I cant understand how the behaviours are different in both cases.

Comment: You can use Log property on DbContext to show the SQL Statement generated. This can help you to understood the Linq To SQL generated query. Helpfull link : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b3c71ae-f706-4ef7-b3ed-4a9fe659449d/faq-item-how-do-i-track-the-linq-to-sql-generated-sql

Comment: @user1812171 What does user1812171 return?

Comment: @Madushan In the case of the first example, Assuming `.GetUsres` (sic) is an IQueryable, the database will be hit twice as well. Once on `.Any` and a second time on `.First()`.

Comment: @user1812171 you do not specify which flavor of LINQ you are using. The answer for LINQ to Objects and LINQ to SQL/EF could be quite different.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be entirely dependant on your implementation of `MyProgram.GetUsres();`

If this function is expensive then case 2 will be slower as the function will be called twice.  That being said it also depends what MyPRogram.GetUsres() does.  If it returns an IEnumerable() the is expensive to calculate then this advantage disappears.

An alternative would be to process once

```
var username = MyProgram.GetUsers()
                        .Select(x => x.Username)
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName.Lower("xyz"));
```

Username will either be the first match or `null` on no match.

This is assuming that your Lower function returns a bool, I'm assuming it does `x.UserName.ToLower() =="xyz"`, if so then you want.

```
var username = MyProgram.GetUsers()
                        .Select(x => x.Username)
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => 
                              String.Compare(x,
                                             "xyz",
                                             StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it appears that you are asking if you should check for the existence of a thing and only fetch it if it exists. I would recommend flipping the logic around to try to get the one thing (which is a requisite action for Any/Exists) and return it if found or return null otherwise. In this case, just use FirstOrDefault and skip the Any check entirely thereby reducing your iteration/database request count to 1 instead of 2.

As an aside, if you are doing this against a database, most databases use case insensitive string comparisons, so you can drop the .Lower conversion.